# Python's support for hexadecimal escapes in the replacement text

Tags: python, regex, pep

Could not found a corresponding PEP or a bug for one problem in Python's `re` module.

Does anyone know if the following is planned to be fixed?

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacenonprint.html):

> Python does not support hexadecimal escapes in the replacement text
>   syntax, even though it supports \xFF and \uFFFF in string constants.

But it actually supports standard escapes like `\n`, `\r`, etc.

So, for example one cannot replace `'<'` character with `'>'` character using hexadecimal escapes:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\x3c', r'\x3e', '\x3c')
'\\x3e'
```

Instead of `'\\x3e'` it should be `'>'`.

Using escaped `\n` works fine:

```
>>> re.sub(r'a', r'\n', 'a')
'\n'
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPD:** Not using the raw string is not an option. For example if pattern and replacement strings are stored in a config file, so if I write \x3e in it, it will become `'\\x3e'` when read, instead of `'>'`.

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround I know if is to not use a raw string for the replacement text and instead allow normal string evaluation to make `\x3e` into `>`. This works because, as you noted, python strings do support such sequences.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\x3c', '\x3e', '\x3c')
'>'
```

This means that in more complex replacement text you need more escapes, which could make it less readable, but at least it works.

I don't know if there is any plan to improve on this. I took a look at the existing documentation for the [python 3.4 re module](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub) (under dev) and found no mention of including this kind of support.

However, if you have a need for more complex logic on the replacement, you can pass a function instead of replacement text for the `repl` argument of `re.sub`.

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for the reply! Not using the raw string is not an option. For example if pattern and replacement strings are stored in a config file, so if I write \x3e in it, it will become `'\\x3e'` when read, instead of `'>'`.

Comment: Using function as `repl` parameter is a really nice feature, thanks for mentioning. I have totally forgot about it. Either way you should use some method for converting hexadecimal characters' representations in a string to the actual characters. I cannot think of other way than using `eval()`...